# Comparing 2-D char array in C++

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    int b[10];
    char a[50][50];

    cout<<"Dictionary\n";
    cout<<"Enter the no. of enteries you want to enter:";
    cin>>n;

    // Function 1 & 2 : To add keys and values
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the name:";
        cin>>a[i];

        for(j=0;j<i;)
        {
            if(a[j]==a[i])
            {
                cout<<"no";
                cin>>a[i];
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }

        cout<<"Enter the marks:";
        cin>>b[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if we enter 2 entries ... which same name... then why its not going in the `if(a[i]==a[j])` ???
like if a[i]='rohan' amd a[j]='rohan' too but it is not coming equal.... for initializing i can only use char

Comment: I seriously advise moving that `using` clause out of this file entirely; at a minimum move it *after* your include files. if your compiler did not warn you about using an anonymous namespace it isn't doing its job very well.

Answer (score 3):

Array type objects are second-class citizens in C++. For example, comparing two arrays with `==` will not compare the array objects themselves. Instead, it will compare pointers to the first elements of each array. In this way, two arrays will only compare equal with `==` if they are the same array object (because then their first elements have the same address).

If you want to compare C-style strings (that is, null-terminated arrays of `char`), you need to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

However, I recommend using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for your strings instead. They are much easier to handle - they allow comparison with `==` (and many other useful functions) and do not expect you to put an arbitrary 50 character limit on your strings.

Comment: thank you for the advice .... really helpful.... but the thing is assignment says no use of STRING

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare an array of characters like this. This comparison operator is essentially comparing the addresses of the two arrays which are not the same.

Why not just use memcmp (or memicmp - for case-insesetive) or even better use std::string?